# How can I share clover coverage data between maven and IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, clover

I have a multi-module [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) project.  I'm using [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) as my IDE.
I have Maven configured with the [clover](/questions/tagged/clover) plugin to automatically instrument on build.
How can I get IntelliJ to recognize those changes and refresh its coverage data.(**NOTE:** having to click the "Refresh Coverage" toolbar button is fine.)

I've tried configuring **maven-clover2-plugin** like so:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <baseDir>${project.basedir}</baseDir>
      <cloverMergeDatabase>
        ${project.basedir}.clover\cloverMerge.db
      </cloverMergeDatabase>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>main</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>instrument</goal>
          <goal>aggregate</goal>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>site</id>
        <phase>pre-site</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>instrument</goal>
          <goal>aggregate</goal>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>clean</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <goals><goal>clean</goal></goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I then configured my project settings to use:
`.clover\cloverMerge.db` and checked the *relative to project directory.* checkbox.

But that didn't work.

**NOTE:**
At the bottom of [Configuring Instrumentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Configuring+instrumentation) it says
**Do not set these locations explicitly if you have a multi-module project.**
So I also tried leaving the location as the default for both Maven and IDEA and that didn't work either.

Also in the [Clover for IDEA installation GUIDE - Known Issues](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover-for-IDEA+Installation+Guide)

> If you are using the Maven build tool, you should avoid using the same > IntelliJ output directory as Maven does. As Maven uses the  `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` directories,
>   avoid specifying these ones. The `clover.db` location for IntelliJ should also be distinct from that used by Maven.

*WHY* should they be distinct is there some file corruption issue?  If they're kept distinct then *HOW* can I get awesome coverage highlighting/etc, without having to repeat builds in a completely separate process?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you didn't use IDEA's built-in builder to compile the code and the Clover-for-IDEA plugin to generate code coverage for it?

Comment: Because when I build my application for deployment I'm using maven. I'd prefer to test from the same build process I deploy with than a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally figured out an answer.  I'm leaving this here for posterity.

The solution is complicated and somewhat of a Hack but it ***WORKS***.

1. Update the parent projects **pom.xml** file

   - cloverDB:   `<cloverDatabase>${project.basedir}.clover\clover.db</cloverDatabase>`
   - Merge CloverDB:
     `<cloverMergeDatabase>
     ${project.basedir}.clover\cloverMerge.db
     </cloverMergeDatabase>`
2. Create your Unit Tests to Run in **IntelliJ IDEA**

   - setup a *Before launch* - *Run Maven Goal*
     `clean clover2:setup prepare-package -DSkipTests`
     [image: Run Configuration for Unit tests screen]
3. Create a Maven Run Configuration

   - Make the Unit-Tests a *Before launch* condition
   - In the command line have Maven run `clover2:aggregrate`
     [image: Run Configuration to have Maven Run the tests and aggregate the results]
4. Update Intellij Project Settings for clover to point to the merge file

   - Make sure the **Relative to project directory.** checkbox is checked.
   - **InitString** to *User specified* with the value the same as your pom file.
     in my case:  **.clover\cloverMergeDB**
     [image: Settings Screen with CheckBox Checked and File name]
5. Once the command is run, just click the *Referesh Coverage* icon to see and work with the coverage data in idea.

   - If the tests fail you will also have the nice *IntelliJ Test runner Tab* to figure out why.

Comment: Your hack looks quite well. However, I think you can optimize it a little bit. Instead of having cloverDatabase + cloverMergeDatabase + using clover2:aggregate to merge databases you could define an absolute path in the cloverDatabase tag. This will cause that Clover will store its data in the same clover.db file for all modules instrumented. Thanks to this you won't have to call clover2:aggregate.

Comment: There's one drawback, however. Having a single clover.db for all modules may have some performance impact for large projects (as the database file has to be updated many times during one build). It depends on your hardware and the code base size, but I'd say that performance drop is not significant for projects having less than 500 modules and less than 1 MLOC.

Comment: It's also possible to use a Maven run configuration to execute tests, e.g.: "clean clover2:setup test". However, you'd have to see test results in Clover's "Test Runs" view instead of IDEA's test runner tab.

Answer (score 0):

*At the bottom of Configuring Instrumentation it says
Do not set these locations explicitly if you have a multi-module project.*

Documentation actually says: *Do not set these locations explicitly **(using absolute path)** if you have a multi-module project.* The reason is simple - if you use an absolute path, then you will not have a separate clover.db for every module, but only a single clover.db file.

*"If you are using the Maven build tool, you should avoid using the same IntelliJ output directory as Maven does. As Maven uses the target/classes and target/test-classes directories, avoid specifying these ones" [...] WHY should they be distinct is there some file corruption issue?*

The problem is as follows: IntelliJ IDEA uses it's own engine to compile sources. It means that it does not have to call the original project's build system (a Maven, for instance) to compile sources.

It means that:
 - if you have a Maven-based project and it has the Clover-for-Maven plugin installed and 
 - at the same time you have the Clover-for-IDEA installed in the IntelliJ IDE
 - and these two Clover integrations use the same output folders for classes and databases

... then these two Clover integrations may start overwriting their files.

In most cases this is not a desired behaviour because any source code modification / project rebuild action etc in IDEA will trigger source recompilation; which can delete results obtained previously by Clover-for-Maven.

Comment: A rebuild should only add *more* coverage data. It should only be a clean type action that should blow the data away.

Comment: IDEA recompiles a source file if it has been modified. As the file has new content, coverage data previously recorded for it (no matter whether by Clover-for-Maven or Clover-for-IDEA) is outdated. For this reason, such file should be instrumented again and code coverage for the file should be recorded again.

Comment: By the way: in Clover-for-Eclipse there's an option whether to clean all coverage data on project rebuild or not (Window > Preferences > Clover > When rebuilding the project ...). 

Clover-for-IDEA does not have such option, however you can can define whether to trigger a full rebuild if some of Clover's options are changed (in "File > Settings > Clover (project settings) > Compilation tab > Rebuild settings"). You can also specify how to refresh data (Clover settings > View tab > Refresh policy) or how old coverage files shall be loaded (Clover settings > View tab > Span).